# Google Maps API V3 slow adding Markers using data.addGeoJson

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am adding 325 features to 4 different maps (at different zoom levels) using `map.data.addGeoJson()`. Roughly half the features are markers and half are polygons. The Polygons render nearly instantaneously. But it takes another 6 full seconds for the markers to show up on the map.

If I only build one map, it still takes 0.5-2 seconds for the markers to show.

Is there anything I can do to speed things up?

Here is my code:

```
function addSites(map, geoJSON) {
    map.data.setStyle(setSitesStyle);
    map.data.addGeoJson(geoJSON)
}

function setSitesStyle(feature) {

    var searchDist = getSearchDistFromListTypes(feature.getProperty('ListTypes').split('~'));

    return ({
        fillColor: searchDist.FontColor,
        strokeColor: searchDist.FontColor,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillOpacity: .5,
        clickable: false,
        icon: {
            url: 'images/' + searchDist.Marker + 's.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(26 , 38),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(13, 34),
            label: feature.getProperty('MarkerNo')
        }
    });
}
```

Update: I tried using a simple SVG icon and the performance was no different.

Comment: If whoever downvoted this question could tell me why I would be more than happy to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the DOM was pretty darn big on this page and it took a while for Google Maps to add all of the elements to the DOM.

In my case the page was 95% Handlebars.js so what I did was compile all of the handlebars templates and remember the resulting HTML in an array. Then pushed just the map pages' HTML into the DOM and processed the map data (which was darn fast now.) And then finally loaded the rest of the HTML into the DOM which also was pretty quick.

Since multiple maps can be interspersed throughout the page it was a small challenge to figure out a simple and robust way to get it all woven back together correctly, but I am happy in the end.